# Remove duplication of a specific attribute of an object inside an array - Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting

Consider the following array:

```
    packages = [ 
    {modelName: "flatRate", name:"Enterprise", price: "$150"},
    {modelName: "flatRate", name:"Gold", price: "$190"},
    {modelName: "usageBased", name:"Enterprise", price: "$50"},
    {modelName: "userBased", name:"Extreme", price: "$50"},
    ]
```

**What I want to achieve is:**

Use the **packages.modelName** as a heading and list all its items under it without repeating modelName. For Example:

*flatRate*

Enterprise ($150) ,  Gold ($190)

*usageBased*

Enterprise ($50)

*userBased*

Extreme ($50)

***Notice how 2 objects having modelName: "flatRate" are shown under one heading.***

**What I've tried:**

Take the packages array use a foreach loop on it and remake the array as:

```
packagesResult = [ 
    { modelname: "flatRate",
      model: [ {name: "Enterprise", price: "$150"} ]
    },
    { modelname: "flatRate",
      model: [ {name: "Gold", price: "$190"} ]
    },
    { modelname: "usageBased",
      model: [ {name: "Enterprise", price: "$50"} ]
    },
    { modelname: "userBased",
      model: [ {name: "Extreme", price: "$50"} ]
    },

 ]
```

and then tried to use a filter on it using observable but didn't work. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would a reduce like so fit your purpose?

```
models = packages.reduce((models, package) => {
 models[package.name] = package.price;
 return models;
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for something like the following:

```
 myPackages = {};
function consolidatePayload() {

  for(let package of packages){
    if(this.myPackages.hasOwnProperty(package.modelName)) {
        this.myPackages[package.modelName][package.name] = package.price;
  } else {
    this.myPackages[package.modelName]= {[package.name]: package.price};
  }
}
```

console.log(this.myPackages);
}

IT gives an and result along the lines of

```
{
  flatRate: {
    Enterprise: "$150",
    Gold: "$190"
  },
  usageBased: {
    Enterprise: "$50"
  },
  userBased: {
    Extreme: "$50"
  }
}
```

EDIT: reduce inspiration, per @Śaeun acreáť

```
function consolidatePayload() {
  let models = this.packages.reduce((models, package) => {
  if(models.hasOwnProperty(package.modelName)) {
    models[package.modelName][package.name]= package.price;
  } else {
  models[package.modelName] = {[package.name]: package.price}
  }
  return models;
 }, {})
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of price types for each model name like below ;)

```js
const result = packages = [{
    modelName: "flatRate",
    name: "Enterprise",
    price: "$150"
  },
  {
    modelName: "flatRate",
    name: "Gold",
    price: "$190"
  },
  {
    modelName: "usageBased",
    name: "Enterprise",
    price: "$50"
  },
  {
    modelName: "userBased",
    name: "Extreme",
    price: "$50"
  },
].reduce( (acc, item, i) => {
  if( i === 0 ) {
    acc.push(modifiedObject(item));
    return acc;
  }
  let foundItem = acc.find(it => it.modelName === item.modelName);
  if (foundItem) {
    addNewPriceType(foundItem, item);
    return acc;
  } else {
    acc.push(modifiedObject(item));
    return acc;
  }
}, [] );

function modifiedObject(item) {
  return {
    modelName : item.modelName,
    model : [ 
      { name : item.name, price : item.price } 
    ]
  };
}

function addNewPriceType(foundItem, item) {
  foundItem.model.push({
    name : item.name,
    price : item.price
  });
} 

console.log(result);
```